# What exactly does PowerShell's -Version parameter do?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

PowerShell's help (`powershell -?`) states:

```
-Version
    Starts the specified version of Windows PowerShell.
```

However, when starting PowerShell 2 with `powershell -Version 1` all things I tried that are only present in v2 and not v1 still work, such as the `-split` operator or the `Get-Random` cmdlet.

So what exactly changes when running PowerShell with the `-Version` parameter if language features and cmdlets that were introduced later still exist and work? This makes testing scripts for PowerShell v1 a bit harder since I don't always remember what has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this switch does anything especially since 1.0 and 2.0 can't be installed side-by-side.  This switch was put in from the beginning. My guess is that they anticipated being able to run different versions of PowerShell side-by-side.  Perhaps that will happen with some future version that installs side-by-side and then this switch will be actually useful.

Comment: Hm, makes me wonder why they catch versions other than 1 or 2 and output an error message *(»Cannot start Windows PowerShell version 3 because it is not correctly installed.«)* but don't do this for version 1 which would have the same error, actually.

Comment: Another guess - they consider 2.0 backwards compatible with 1.0?

Comment: Probably the same reason why 2.0 installs to the system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 directory.

Comment: I've actually confirmed that PowerShell 1.0 and 2.0 run just fine side by side if you take the GAC'd assemblies out of the equation. So I wouldn't be surprised if someday powershell.exe is just a launcher much like how *.sln files are associated with a Visual Studio stub that opens the correct version.

Comment: Since some time has passed, this does seem to have an effect on version 3.0 specifying 2.0 as version