# PowerShell $PSVersionTable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0, powershell-3.0

I have PowerShell 3.0 installed, and I wish to emulate v1.0

When I launch PowerShell 3.0 with -Version 1  $PSVersionTable reports:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5456
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1

If I use the -Version 2 parameter I get the same result
If I use the -Version 3 parameter I get version 3.

Question, why can't I emulate version 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992196/what-exactly-does-powershells-version-parameter-do), I don't think you can run 1 & 2 side-by-side without some surgery on the GAC (so it would follow that 1, 2 & 3 don't all co-exist either - only 2 & 3, because 2 & 3 *were* designed to run side by side). Version 2 was meant to completely replace version 1, AFAICT.

Comment: I understand your logic, and it confirms what I see.  I just tried PowerShell 2 with -Version 1.  It reported to be version 2!

Answer (score 1):

You can not run V1 using the side by side stuff. That was never supported. You CAN run V2 from V3, but not V1.